# Running Tomcat without having to specify the port 8080

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat9

I have an issue with accessing my website without having to specify the port number in the URL.

I have a droplet on DigitalOcean and have followed their guide on how to install and setup Tomcat. I have deployed my ROOT.war file and I can access my website by going to myipaddress:8080.

From the research I did, I understand that to access my website without having to specify the port I need to change it in server.xml from 8080 to 80.

This stops my application from working, the server's running, but I can no longer access my website.

It just says this site can't be reached.

Most people suggest to edit /etc/default/tomcat9 and set authbind to yes.

I simply don't have this file anywhere, event after installing authbind, I have looked in every directory, any suggestions?

Comment: please specify your Operating system

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.6 x64

Comment: Can you access the server locally ? like http://localhost/[yourApplicationContext] ? if you can then @MahmoudEltayeb comment would be the next step to allow HTTP and your site should work on port 80

Comment: There is a workaround I always use by using a reverse proxy (nginx for example) that listen remotely to port 80 and forward the traffic to your tomcat port

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

1) Change tomcat port to 80

2) Remove the existing ROOT folder from webapps in tomcat

3) In file tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml you need to comment valve tag to 
   allow manger to be accessed.

```
    <Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
</Context>
```

change it to

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" /> -->

</Context>
```

3) deploy your war file as ROOT.war file

4) start the server

5) Now try to access by domain name

Note : if your application having context path, you may need to try domain_name/context_path

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After changing the port to 80 I can no longer access the manager console or the app itself. Also, I don't have a domain yet so I am just putting my IP Address.

Comment: so are you telling that you cannot modify context.xml?

Comment: I think I can, when I save it and access it again it is still set to port 80? Is there other way to double check?

Comment: I have followed these two guides when setting up a server:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

Hope it helps

Comment: When you change the port to 80, by hitting the ip address (like 25.25.25.25) without the port from the browser , you should be able to see tomcat Root page.  Now when you click tomcat manager it won't be accessible unless the context.xml file modified as shown above (because, by default tomcat manager only accessible from the local only). That is how you can double check that the file is modified and working. please make sure you restart the server after modifying context.xml

Comment: Hi, The tomcat manager was accessible when the port was set to 8080, once I've changed it to 80 it stopped working. When hitting my IP address without the port it just says this site can't be reached. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following as root

```
ufw allow HTTP
```